# Maven install or clean depending upon changes

Tags: maven, maven-compiler-plugin

We have a huge set of modules in our project and therefore we use **mvn install** to save time on builds. But, it doesn't seem to handle file deletes very well. It doesn't delete the deleted files from the target during compilation.

Is there a way for maven to perform a "clean install" when there are deletes or even changes to the module. And perform "install" if there are no changes.

Or, is there an option in install to detect file deletions and update the target accordingly?

Thank you.

Comment: How could you save time using `mvn install` ? The `target` folder can simply be deleted if you do `mvn clean install` Furthermore the question is what you mean by `target` cause it sounds you don't mean the `target` folder ? I assume you mean the files in the local cache `$HOME/.m2/repositroy`?

Comment: "mvn install" does an incremental build i.e. it will only compile the changed files; and therefore faster than "mvn clean install". By target, I actually meant the target folder.

Comment: Your assumption is simply wrong cause if you `mvn install` will run the whole life cycle which means for example run the tests etc. If you `mvn clean install` will make remove the whole `target` folder...And where is stated that `mvn install` will do an incremental build? The best approach to save time is using parallelized build via `mvn -T 3 clean install` if you have a multi module build...or build only the changed modules via `mvn -pl TheModuleYouLike -amd clean install`...

Comment: @praveenj is right `mvn install` is faster than `mvn clean install`. See [`useIncrementalCompilation`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#useIncrementalCompilation).